# RevMob fullscreen ad crashes on iOS

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, revmob

If I tap on a fullscreen **ad** and close it before the **ad** has time to open Safari or the AppStore the app crashes, with the following error:

```
[RevMob] Initializing Fullscreen.
[RevMob] Ad received: (200).
[RevMob] Fullscreen clicked.
[RevMob] Loading iTunes url.
[RevMob] Fullscreen closed.
[RevMob] Opening iTunes.
 ***** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM insertObject:atIndex:]: object cannot be nil'**
```

if there was a loading screen to block user interaction while RevMob take is time to take action that would not happen... I tried to cover the ad with a loading screen but I couldnt manage to do that... is there any solution for that?

--

**I have 2 iVars to control revMob:**

```
RevMobFullscreen* _revMobFullScreen;
BOOL _revMobFullScreenLoaded;
```

**I'm pre-loading the fullscreen ad this way:**

```
- (void)cacheFullScreenRevMob{

    //Get rid of old fullscreen ad and create a new one
    //This is need in order to (re)load an fullscreen ad
    [_revMobFullScreen release], _revMobFullScreen = nil;
    _revMobFullScreen = [[RevMobAds session] fullscreen];
    [_revMobFullScreen retain];

    //Pre load the ad for the next time

    _revMobFullScreenLoaded = NO;

    [_revMobFullScreen loadWithSuccessHandler:^(RevMobFullscreen *fs) {
        _revMobFullScreenLoaded = YES;

    } andLoadFailHandler:^(RevMobFullscreen *fs, NSError *error) {
        _revMobFullScreenLoaded = NO;

    } onClickHandler:nil onCloseHandler:^{
        [self postNotificationOnMainThreadFullAdDidFinish];
    }];
}
```

**And then, thats how I display a fullscreen revmob ad:**

```
- (BOOL)showFullScreenRevMob{

    BOOL didShow = NO;
    if (_revMobFullScreenLoaded) {
        [_revMobFullScreen showAd];
        didShow = YES;
    }

    //Cache for the next time
    [self cacheFullScreenRevMob];

    return didShow;
}
```

Comment: The application will also crash if theres a timeout when trying to open the ad url

Comment: This was a bug on version 5.6.1
RevMob has just released a fix for that with version 5.6.2

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: As the comment by @João it was a bug fixed on version 5.6.2

Comment: please take another look at the question, I edited it adding some code. Yes I am retaining the fullscreen ad. @diogot

Comment: They've fixed it just yesterday! Version 5.6.2 works just fine.